# Receiving multiple instances of data from Behavior Subject every time component is initialised

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple router where i am calling a service and receiving the data from the behavior Subject...When i navigate to another route and comeback i am receiving multiple values from the subject...How can i destroy all the observers of a subject and create new subject whenever i need...? Here is the plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OKiljCekSKHO1zJF5MAy?p=preview
I am planning to destroy the observers of a subject in ngOnDestroy...

```
  ngOnDestroy(){
this.srvc.DestroySubject();
 }
```

Can somebody please tell me how to destroy the observers of a behaviorsubject?

Comment: I don't know if the proposed workaround in my answer is what you want. If you provide more information about the actual problem you're trying to solve I might be able to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is expected.

```
export class Sample1 {
  constructor(public srvc:HeroService) {
      this.srvc.Data.subscribe(data=> {
        console.log(data);
      });
      this.srvc.GetData();
  }
}
```

In the constructor you subscribe to `srvc.Data` and because `Data` is a `BehaviorSubject` it returns the most recent emitted value. You initialize `Data` with `null`, therefore at first there is no data.

Then in the constructor you call `this.srvc.GetData()` this causes an event to be emitted and be received by the subscription (the lines before).

If you navigate away and back, then `Sample1` is initialized again and the constructor is executed. The first thing is that is subscribes to `srvc.Data`. and it gets the last emitted value which is `Received Data` from the previous call to `GetData()` (when we first navigated to Heroes).

The next thing is the call to `this.srvc.GetData()` which again emits `Received Data` and the subscription gets this value passed.

**Workaround**

To fix it you could move the call to `this.srvc.GetData();` to the service instead like

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  Data: BehaviorSubject<RepairOrder> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor() {
    this.GetData();
  }

  GetData(){
    this.Data.next('Recieved Data');
  }
  DestroySubject(){
    //alert('hi');
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/T92HmstT8bgLEMP5pq4u?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you...this is a good answer... But I have update my plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OKiljCekSKHO1zJF5MAy?p=preview to give to more info...I have a button in second route,when i click on that button i am calling a service where subject emits data and i will navigate to other component...How can i do in this case sir. Should i change the workaround for this case?

Comment: Tricky. In this case there seem to exist two instances of `Sample1`. Unsubscribing in `ngOnDestroy()` fixed it http://plnkr.co/edit/o2Onm3G43m1siDo7bA4H?p=preview