# What's an alternative for root scope in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want the child component to access the shared service take the data and after injecting the child component to main component. I want the data of the *sharedservice(rootscope)* to directly put the data in mainComponents HTML, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707789/use-rootscope-variables-in-my-html).

**mainComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ChildComponent} from './child';
import {AppServiceService} from './app-service.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,

  selector: 'rootscope-app',

  templateUrl: 'rootscope.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['rootscope.component.css'],

  directives:[ChildComponent]

})

export class RootscopeAppComponent {

  title = 'rootscope works!';

  display:any;

  constructor(appServiceService:AppServiceService){  

    this.display=appServiceService.getter();

  }
}
```

**sharedService.ts**

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()

export class AppServiceService {

  ser = "hello i am from service";

  public data: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  settter(data: any) {

    this.data = data;

  }

  getter() {

    return this.data;
  }
}
```

**childComponent of mainComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {AppServiceService} from '../app-service.service'

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,

  selector: 'app-child',

  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['child.component.css']

})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  dispaly: string;

  constructor(appServiceService: AppServiceService) {

    this.dispaly = "Child component binding...";

    appServiceService.settter(this.dispaly);

  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: `$rootScope` and `$scope` both are not in Angular2. You can think of `shareService` and inject it into `boostrap` function. This way you will be able to share you data throughout application(HTML as well).

Comment: but then also i can't access the data which is there in shareService directly in html without using the that html's component

Comment: you can use shareservice data into HTML directly. Just inject it into your controller that's it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - What is equivalent to Root Scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985009/angular-2-what-is-equivalent-to-root-scope)

Comment: it is same thing but using shared service i was not able to access the data in HTML .

Comment: This only works if the constructor in `ChildComponent` is executed before the constructor of `RootscopeAppComponent` which I wouldn't rely upon. I think it's better to use a `BehaviorSubject` and `subscribe()` (like shown for example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429824/receiving-multiple-instances-of-data-from-behavior-subject-every-time-component/37430037#37430037)

Answer (score 4):

**$rootScope** and **$scope** both are not available in Angular2. You can think to use **service (shareService)** and inject it into **boostrap** function. This way you will be able to share data throughout application(HTML as well).

Look at here. http://plnkr.co/edit/7A21ofKNdi0uvbMgLUDZ?p=preview

```
bootstrap(App, [sharedService]);
```

**sharedService**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

@Injectable()
export class sharedService {
    name="micronyks";
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'thecontent',
    template: `
    <h1>Component II - {{ss.name}}   </h1>
        `
})
export class TheContent {
  constructor(private ss: sharedService) {
    console.log("content started");
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to access the shared service directly in html like we had angular as mentioned above.@Component({
  selector: 'thecontent',
    template: `
    <h1>Component II - {{sharedservice.name}}   </h1>
        `
})// i don't want to create an object
export class TheContent {
  constructor(private ss: sharedService) {
    console.log("content started");
  }

Comment: @micronyks when I change a data in the service, it will be reflected in the other pages?

Comment: @KamuranSönecek yes it will reflect in other pages but you have to make sure that all pages share the single instance of the service else it will not work.

Comment: $rootScope in  angularJS will be watched for value change. But the example you have give won't work if we want to keep the data updated in injected component.

Comment: @PaulRichard for that you can use `RXJS` library and its `observables`. eg. `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: @micronyks yes I agree, please update your answer with the Observable implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the desired output is that we want to use shared values inside any template, then using a service is not an answer.

The solution is making a base class to all components, where everything we need globally resides.

create a class, name it `BaseComponent`

```
export class BaseComponent{

   constructor(){}

   public someMethod(): string{
     return "some string";
   }

   //and whatever methods you need, a method can call services and return data from it

}
```

and make every component extends it

```
export class TestPage extends BaseComponent {
```

and inside its HTML template

```
<span> {{someMethod()}} </span>
```

**or alternatively** if you want a change in the view (template) to be fired from a service function call, you can place a callback in the service and assign it from the component so it will be fired whenever the service function called, take this case as an example

In my case I wanted to show a message that can be fired from any component, so I placed it in the `app.component.html` which survives along the app lifetime

```
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div [hidden]="!msg" (click)="msg=''" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            {{msg}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

inside the `app.component.ts`

```
constructor(private main: MainService){}

msg: string = "";
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.main.showMsg = (msg)=>{this.msg = msg;}
}
```

the `MainService` is the service that contains the callback, as you see below

```
//main.service.ts
public showMsg:(msg: string)=>void;
```

now from any component, with the main service registered in the constructor, you can show the message as follows

```
if(this.main.showMsg){
     this.main.showMsg("the message text");
}
```

Comment: You cannot really share some data (think static data)  when using base component and inheritance like this, but yes the functions can be used. This is like a base class and concept of inheritance is meant for different purpose

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by using angular BehaviorSubject and asObservable

Check below example code

Service file

```
@Injectable()
export class commonService {
    private data = new BehaviorSubject('');
    currentData = this.data.asObservable()

    constructor() { }

    updateMessage(item: any) {
        this.data.next(item);
    }

}
```

Component

Set the data from any component

```
 constructor(private _data: commonService) { }
 shareData() {
      this.currentValue = this.queryTerm;
      this._data.updateMessage(this.currentValue);
  }
```

Listen from any component

```
constructor(private _data: commonService) { }
ngOnInit() {
        this._data.currentData.subscribe(currentData => this.currentValue = currentData)
    }
```

You can communicate between any component using this way.