# Angular behavior subject duplicate data issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two sibling components within my parent. The siblings need to talk to each other, so I use a shared service with a `BehaviorSubject`.

When I navigate away from my parent and come back, the component that is subscribed to the `BehaviorSubject`, `Component2`, appears to be receiving two sets of data.

From what I can tell, its the last set that it had and then the new set it receives when `Component1` tells the service to call `next()` after coming back to the parent for the second time.

In `Component2`, I have an `ngOnDestroy` method that is calling `unsubscribe` on the `BehaviorSubject`.

I am missing something here? Do I need to somehow empty or clear whatever the `BehaviorSubject` has in my `ngOnDestroy` method?

The very first time this all runs, it works just fine. It is only when the `BehaviorSubject` already has data that it is sending two sets.

---

**Update:**
I *think* I know what could be happening but I am not 100% sure. When I load the components for the first time, I subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject` which initializes with `null`. `Component1` then makes its first call, gets data, and updates the `BehaviorSubject` by calling `next()`.

Now, when we leave and come back, `Component2` is re-subscribing to the `BehaviorSubject` which returns the last set of data it has, causing my `results` to be `true` and running `fetchMapRules()`. In this process, `Component1` is fetching data and when it has been received, its then calling `next` on the `BehaviorSubject`, sending the second "New" set of data.

What would be the best fix for this? Changing it to a `Subject` so it doesn't retain the previous data, or calling `next(null)` in my `ngOnDestroy()` method so when we come back a second time, we have no previous data to subscribe to?

---

**Component 1 (sibling) - versions**:

```
mapVersionsData: any;

constructor(
    private _mapsService: MapsService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchMapVersions(1);
}

/* 
    Fetch a list of all the versions for the target we specified.
    This method is only ever invoked the one time. 
*/
fetchMapVersions(targetID) {
    this._mapsService
        .fetchMapVersions(targetID)
        .then(versionsData => {
            this.mapVersionsData = versionsData;
            this._mapsService.updateCurrentSelectedVersion(this.mapVersionsData);
        });
}
```

**Component 2 (sibling) - rules**

```
mapRulesSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(
    private _mapsService: MapsService
) {
    this.mapRulesSubscription = this._mapsService.currentSelectedVersion$.subscribe(
        results => {
            if (results) {
                // The two sets of data cause this method two run two times, passing it both sets of data which is obviously going to cause problems.
                this.fetchMapRules(results['RuleVersionID']);
            }
        }
    );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.mapRulesSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Service:**

```
private currentSelectedVersionData = new BehaviorSubject<object>(null);
currentSelectedVersion$ = this.currentSelectedVersionData.asObservable(); 

// Call next to let our subscribers know about the currently selected version
updateCurrentSelectedVersion(version: object) {
    this.currentSelectedVersionData.next(version);
}

// Call to DB
fetchMapVersions(TargetID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchMapVersions', { "targetID": TargetID }, { "headers": this.headers })
            .map((result: Response) => result.json())
            .subscribe((results) => resolve(results));
    });
};
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like changing it to a Subject would fix the issue. Both are Observables at their core. BehaviorSubjects return the previous value upon subscription causing an immediate action upon subscription, whereas a Subject just subscribes to the observable and waits until something comes through the pipe to perform an action.

Comment: Obviously the trick with a "Subject" is that if you subscribe to it after the data you need has already been 'pushed', you might run into issues.

Comment: Another thing you can do is just wrap the "action" portion of your subscription with an `if` statemetn that makes sure that it isn't a `null` value. I have done that or something similar in a ton of cases.

Comment: @joshrathke on your last comment, thats when `if(results)` is doing. `null` is the default value of the `BehaviorSubject` so it never runs that inner method until it has data that was called by `next()`. However, when coming back to the parent the second time, `results = first data set subject has` causing it to run on subscribe, and then a second time once `Component1` calls `next` on the data it gets. Right?

Comment: Is the second set of data the same as the first? Sorry I guess I am a little confused.

Comment: @joshrathke - In my example it would be because I am passing the same ID so it would  load the same set of data. However, `this.fetchMapVersions(anyNumber);` could be called resulting in an entirely new set of data coming through as the second response.

Comment: K, so you are actually getting 2 sets of data, correct? Because that would indicate to me at least that you somehow have 2 subscriptions running. BehaviorSubject doesn't return the 'first' and 'last' values. It only returns 1 value, the current value. The key difference between it and a Subject is that upon subscription it immediately hands out the previous value. After that, its basically a Subject and should only be handing out 1 value at a time..

Comment: When coming back to the component a second time, it is re-subscribing to the subject. Since that subject already has data, thats what is returned to `component2` (the last data it had..). However, once `component1` has finished its `http` call, it is then updating that subject with its data (the new set of data) which is causing the method within the subscription to run 1 time for the old data and 1 time for the new data. Does that make sense ?

Comment: As a test, I tried changing it to a `subject` and it worked fine. I also left it as a `BehaviorSubject` and just called `updateCurrentSelectedVersion(null)` in my parents `onDestroy()` method. This also seemed to work fine. Not sure the best option of the two but that at least identifies that the issue

Comment: Are you sure the component is actually being destroyed? You might have a rogue component operating a second subscription in the background.

Comment: The only reason I ask is that ngOninit and the constructor only get called once. So a component can't really "re-subscribe" but it is possible that it's not being destroyed and a new one is being created with a separate subscription.

Comment: @joshrathke I would assume so - My parent component wraps the two children with an `*ngIf="mapMetaData"`. When I leave my parent, `ngOnDestroy(){ this.mapMetaData = null; } ` is called. I assume the `*ngIf` is now false, destroying those children?

Comment: I added a `console.log` in my service method that calls next on the `BehaviorSubject`. This only ever runs one time. The `console.log` in my subscription runs 2 times (after we leave and come back) containing the old data and the new data. Not sure if this changes anything but this service is defined in my `providers` at the `appModule` level, not per component.

Comment: Is it a lazy loaded module that houses the component?

Comment: No, they are loaded up front

Comment: Hmmmm. Is there any reason you aren't just using standard data binding between components to achieve this? The parent can pull in the values from the service and redistribute accordingly.

Comment: I briefly tried using things like `Input()`, `Output()` and `EventEmitter` to get all this working but I couldn't seem to keep things in sync. I just decided to treat the siblings as if they were not related to the parent, which they really aren't other than the parent providing the `targetID` from the route. Shared Service seemed to the the suggested way to go

Comment: This seems to be an identical issue to what I am facing - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37430037/2628921